# HDMI TV capped at 24 Hz

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, tv

Two weeks ago, I bought a new Lenovo Y540 (81SXCTO1WW) with a 144 Hz screen. That screen works well, and the switchable graphics (Intel UHD 630 and Nvidia RTX 2060) also work properly. I have updated the drivers via Device Manager (Intel driver is from 4/07/2019) and for the Nvidia driver I have GeForce Experience.

Now I wanted to connect my laptop to my Pioneer PDP-427XA TV via HDMI, but there were a few problems there.

1. The graphics driver for the TV is automatically the Nvidia driver. I can't use the Intel card for this: if I turn off the Nvidia card in device management, the TV just goes black. All settings must also be made via the Nvidia control panel.
2. The biggest problem is that the HDMI output is capped at 24 Hz, while I can achieve 60 Hz with a different laptop, via the same cable and input. Another input and cable gives the same result. If I try to set 60 Hz manually (through the Nvidia control panel), it will not accept it if it is interlaced. If it is progressive, it is accepted but the screen remains black again. Gaming at 24 Hz is not playable. There is also a lot of screen tearing.

By the way, I can choose the frame rate on my TV when inputting the TV box from the TV provider, this option is switched off when connecting the HDMI from my laptop.

Does anyone knows what the problem could be here? Or has anyone ever experienced a similar problem? The TV is several years old, but the hdmi works perfectly with another laptop (Acer and Asus tested).

Comment: 1) Your HDMI output is physically wired to the NVVIDIA HDMI output. 2) Your NVIDIA HDMI output probably has a max clock rate (can you achiever a higher framerate with a lower resolution?).

Comment: While an Nvidia 20 series definitely *should* support up to 4k @ 60Hz, it is possible that Lenovo put something in the chain that does not support the refresh rate. You should check your manual to see if the HDMI output is limited in any way.